# cleanDataEmbeddedCassandra(KEYSPACE) converts the table names into lowercase

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I'm using Embedded Cassandra server to test a spring boot application that has spring-data-cassandra.

I used the following method to clean up the tables: 
`EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanDataEmbeddedCassandra(KEYSPACE);`

However this method throws an exception because the table names are converted into lowercase when the truncate query is executed while my table names have uppercase letters.

Is there anyway to solve this problem with Keeping my table names as they are?

This is one of my tables:

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;

@Table(value = "MyTable", forceQuote = true)
public class MyTable {

    private String s1;

    private String s2;
}
```

For now I cleaned up the tables manually by using deleteAll() method for all cassandraRepositories that I have in my application.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea on spring boot. But in cassandra if you are going with uppercase keyspace or table name you should be using quotes.

Example:

```
select * from "EXample"."Test";
```